# Memcached::increment() increases value by 2 in PHP for appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

The following code prints a number incremented by 2 every time I reload the page.

```
<?php
    //Memcahce
    $memcache = new Memcached;
    $memcache->increment('hits');
    echo "hitcount = ".$memcache->get('hits');
```

output

```
hitcount = 2
```

Expected : It should increment by 1.

I tried setting it to 2 and 5 but still it increments by 4 and 10 respectively.

Comment: Check your routing - loading a page in a browser will also request a favicon. If you're directing all requests at this code, then a single load in a browser will hit the code twice. You should see the 2nd request in your logs.

Comment: @Greg yeah just realized that, there was a wildcard mapping to this page, so the favicon requests must have been landing in the script as well. Thanks

Comment: @Greg — please move your comment to an answer, sounds like it's the solution to the original problem statement.